# How to focus on search bar without default search engine?

Tags: firefox

From this [guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly), I know there's a shortcut `CMD + K` to focus on search bar.

[image]

It will search with google.

The default search engine can be replaced with one of these:

[image]

I don't want to always type `CMD + K` then `ESC`. What I want is:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean simply changing focus to address bar? F6 works on most/all browsers under Windows at least.

Comment: @TeddHansen Ha! Yep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found CMD + L works really really good!